# Microsoft Access Query Make table SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

Can someone tell me whats wrong with my where clause in this statement in a Access SQL

```
    SELECT * INTO [Enrolled Students]
    FROM [Candidate Details];
    Where Student ID  != 'rejected' OR 'pending' OR 'taster';
```

Or if possible, could it be corrected to where IsNumeric(Student ID)?

I cant seem to figure it out

Thanks Guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * INTO [Enrolled Students]
    FROM [Candidate Details]
    Where [Student ID] not in( 'rejected', 'pending' ,'taster');
```

Comment: Thanks! that did it!
Another Question
I assumed doing this would automatically populate my table every time i entered someone into the original table but it wants me to rerun the Query everytime
is there a way of doing this automatically?

Answer (score 1):

In MS Access

```
SELECT * INTO [Enrolled Students]
    FROM [Candidate Details]
    Where [Student ID]  Not IN ("rejected","pending","taster");
```

It seems that Student ID is a text field if it can contain "rejected". Not In is more convenient in this case, otherwise you would have to say:

```
Where [Student ID]  <> "rejected" And [Student ID] <> "pending" <...>
```

Comment: user1534524 It is not a good idea to constantly run a make table query. For one, it will lead to database bloat. Why do you feel you need to do this?